# Left shift operator with strange behavior

Tags: java

It's just out of curiosity, that, when I do the following:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    byte a = 2;
    byte b = 1;
    byte c = (byte) a<<b;
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

The code will not compile because of *unary numeric promotion that makes variable `a` promoted to int* and thus it will not compile because `int` > `byte`. The compiler throws *possible lossy conversion error*. Until here, **things make sense**.

Writing the same code as:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    byte a = 2;
    byte b = 1;
    byte c = (byte) (a<<b); //the parenthesis were added only.
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Everything works without a problem with the inclusion of just parenthesis, and the left shift operator successfully results in the answer `4`. 
What sorcery is this?

Comment: Simple `byte << byte` yields an `int`. Your parenthesis then casts that back to a `byte`. Without parenthesis you are casting `byte a` to a `byte` (which it already is).

Comment: *"What sorcery is this?"* Are you asking what the left-shift operator does? Or are you asking what the cast does? Neither is sorcery.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, But in theory, isn't saying `(a<<b)` equivalent to saying `a<<b` - both are bytes. Or, are you saying that the numeric promotion doesn't take place when bounding with parenthesis?

Comment: @Andreas, I was actually asking for why the things without parenthesis don't work, while with parenthesis work absolutely fine.

Comment: Without the parenthesis, [**operator precedence**](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) says that `(byte) a<<b` is the same as `((byte) a) << b`, which is very distinct from `(byte) (a << b)`.

Comment: `int t = a<<b;` (you got that right?). Then `byte c = (byte) t;` - you have `int t = ((byte)a)<<b;` - and your total today comes to three dragon eyes or one virgin.

Comment: @Andreas, that makes sense. And because without parenthesis `((byte) a) << b` the right operand gets numeric promotion and therefore the *the possible lossy conversion*. True?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, makes sense. Thanks guys.

Comment: @ShayanAhmad True, except both sides (operands) of the operator are promoted to `int`. The cast of `a` to `byte` is redundant, a no-op, since `a` is already a `byte`. A good IDE would actually warn you about that. The two `byte` values are then promoted to `int` before `<<` is applied, and the result is an `int`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andreas, I can understand it now.